# How to reduce incoming sound in the least intrusive way to the house?

Tags: sound-proofing

We live close to the train tracks about ~150-200 feet away. Luckily the freight train comes very infrequently...maybe once or twice a day.

When the train rolls by, we'll hear noise from the engine (more high frequencies...such as screeching), and once the engine passes, we'll hear low rumbling (low frequencies) from all the train cars that the engine is pulling.

My question is, how do I minimize what I hear inside the house? What is the
**least intrusive way to solve this**.  What I mean is that I can't start knocking down walls or tearing up floors to add sound proofing materials.

[This post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/13350/672) touches on this issue a bit but there weren't that many solutions.

Comment: "I can't start knocking down walls or tearing up floors to add sound proofing materials". Well, there goes any links I could throw at you (>>>) or any suggestions I'd have, so plus one ;)

Comment: Solutions for high and low frequencies will be different. You've probably ruled out your best chances for low frequency but at high frequencies double glazing (even secondary), tightly closing windows, heavy curtains have all been used successfully. Especially in combination. Don't forget doors as well. In upstairs rooms loft insulation can help

Comment: @ChrisH - you could use your comments and post an answer.  :)

Comment: @milesmeow, that was a hasty note jotted down before I lost my signal. If I get the chance to eland it with some links before anyone else does, I will. But the chances are someone will get there first.

Comment: If you have single pane windows upgrading to double or triple pane will yield results. We noticed a difference from normal street noise after installing double pane replacements.

Comment: I lived a bit further from the tracks with an open field between. We put up a solid wood fence that did reduce the noise quite a bit.  Several homes had built large earth mounds and some had cement block walls that probably worked much better.

Comment: The best way is in the answer to the question you linked... Garden wall and sound absorbing landscaping.